# Custom Popen.communicate method gives wrong output

Tags: python, subprocess, python-3.3

Let's start by considering this code:

**proc_stdin.py**

```
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i, line in enumerate(sys.stdin):
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

**test.py**

```
import subprocess


def run_bad(target, input=None):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(
        target,
        universal_newlines=True,
        shell=True,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE if input else subprocess.DEVNULL,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    )

    if input:
        proc.stdin.write(input)
        proc.stdin.flush()
        proc.stdin.close()

    lines = []
    for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline, ""):
        line = line.rstrip("\n")
        lines.append(line)
    proc.stdout.close()

    ret_code = proc.wait()
    return "\n".join(lines)


def run_good(target, input):
    return subprocess.Popen(
        target,
        universal_newlines=True,
        shell=True,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    ).communicate(input=input)[0]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    lst = [
        "",
        "token1",
        "token1\n",
        "token1\r\n",
        "token1\n\n",
        "token1\r\n\ntoken2",
        "token1 token2",
        "token1\ntoken2",
        "token1\r\ntoken2",
        "token1\n\ntoken2",
        "token1\r\n\ntoken2",
        "token1 \ntoken2\ntoken2\n"
    ]
    cmd = "python proc_stdin.py"

    for inp in lst:
        a, b = run_bad(cmd, inp), run_good(cmd, inp)
        if a != b:
            print("Error: {} vs {}".format(repr(a), repr(b)))
        else:
            print("ok: {}".format(repr(a)))
```

**Output:**

```
ok: ''
ok: 'token1'
Error: 'token1' vs 'token1\n'
Error: 'token1\n' vs 'token1\n\n'
Error: 'token1\n' vs 'token1\n\n'
ok: 'token1\n\n\ntoken2'
ok: 'token1 token2'
ok: 'token1\ntoken2'
ok: 'token1\n\ntoken2'
ok: 'token1\n\ntoken2'
ok: 'token1\n\n\ntoken2'
Error: 'token1 \ntoken2\ntoken2' vs 'token1 \ntoken2\ntoken2\n'
```

My question is, why is the output of both `run_bad` & `run_good` not equal in all cases? How would you change the `run_bad` function so the output becomes equal than `run_good`?

You also may wonder, why are you not using directly Popen.communicate for this particular case or other helpers from subprocess module? Well, in the real world case I'm creating a plugin for SublimeText3 which is forcing me to stick to python3.3 (can't use many of the modern subprocess goodies) plus I'd like to inject some callbacks while reading the lines from stdout and that's something I can't do by using the `Popen.communicate` method (as far as I know).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that your emulation of `communicate` may deadlock for long inputs/outputs.

Comment: @DavisHerring Yeah, good point, I was already aware of that but I didn't know a proper way to timeout... For my particular case I was thinking about just killing the process in Sublime

Comment: @DavisHerring Now I've got curious... maybe a proper solution is not about neither killing nor timeout the process... also, it seems this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/14617026/3809375](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14617026/3809375) wouldn't do it in a cross-platform way. Do you have any suggestion for the deadlocks with long inputs/outpus?

Comment: The cheap, portable approach is to use one thread per pipe (so *one* additional thread with `stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you strip newlines from every line and then add them back **between** the lines, what happens to the last newline (if any)?  (There’s no final, empty line after a final newline because your `iter` discards it.)  This is why Python’s `readline` (or line iteration) function *includes* the newlines: they’re necessary to represent the end of the file accurately.